# Finding network devices with multiple ip addresses

Tags: networking, ip, router

I am currently developping an application that scans our network to find all the devices and then add it to a database for another application.
It tries to detect SNMP parameters and device type (Router, Switch, Base station ...)

Currently i'm using fping to get all the ip addresses that are answering my requests. It works good and it is really fast.

But i have an issue : we have several routers (Cisco) that have multiple IP addresses on their interfaces (they are gateways for subnetworks).

So when i start my ping routine, i find dozens of different ip addresses for the same device ! How can i manage to find when two ip or more are from the same device ?

I hope that I've been clear, and if you need more informations, don't hesitate to ask !

Thanks you !

Answer (score -1):

i think you can do that with `tcl` script with `foreach (array)` try something like this [ping-group-of-ip-addresses-with-tcl-script](http://blog.certchaser.com/2008/02/ping-group-of-ip-addresses-with-script.html)

Comment: Nothing there about identifying devices with > 1 IP address.

Comment: not identifying devices just many scopes of ips or  many different subnetmask something like ping scan or ping sweep available ips up and running on my network

Comment: Which doesn't answer the question.